# How to get equivalent of printf_l on Linux?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locale, printf

This function exists on OS X and allows you to pass custom local to the function. setlocale is not thread-safe, and passing locale as parameter is.

If there is no equivalent, any way of locale-independent printf, or printf just for doubles (%g) will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are locale-independent double to string convertion routines at http://www.netlib.org/fp/. String to double conversion is available too. The API is not very nice, but the code works.

Answer (score 4):

You might try [`uselocale`](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib-uselocale-3.html), which sets the thread locale (rather than the process locale) before calling `printf`.

Comment: Not perfect, but works. If anyone else has better answer, go ahead.

Comment: @Sunlight: I think you should amplify your answer a little - but I think you're probably right.  @phjr: the BSD/MacOS X solution with printf_l() is arguably tidier, but the uselocale() should work.

Comment: Note that this solution is ok if you control the whole app, but if you are writing a library routine, it is probably not wise to change the locale process-wide. Hence the desire to want to do formatting in a particular explicit local (or locale-independently, by using the "C" locale).

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole family of locale-independent sprintf family of routines as stb_sprintf: https://github.com/nothings/stb
It's dual licensed as public domain (where possible) and MIT license.